# Overlapping image sliders?

Tags: html, image, slider, overlapping

So... I have to make a working prototype of a website to customize your own cupcake. I really don't know how to make it. I got an image in my head of what I want, but I absolutely don't know how to get it to work.

So, my question is: Is it possible to have multiple image sliders overlap filled with png images so if you click the thumbnails you can build up an image consisting of changeable parts?

I already found some basic image sliders that I would like to use. The thumbnails for the sliders will be hidden in the various menus. Every menu stands for a changeable part of the cupcake, so the thing I want to create with all of the sliders is a personal cupcake.

I made the png files myself so I really hope this idea is possible, because I need this working thing for school and otherwise I really don't know what to do to make it work :X.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Please provide the code that you have so far